# Gradle 8.0 - app: compileDebugJavaWithJavac - error: element value must be a constant expression

Tags: java, android, gradle, gitlab-ci

I recently upgraded to Gradle 8.0 and since then I'm facing an issue while running task "testDebugUnitTest" in a gitlab-ci environment.

The error occurs during the task "compileDebugJavaWithJavac" with the following message:
`error: element value must be a constant expression @BindView(R.id.screen_scan) ^`
When I inspect the R.id bytecode from a generated APK build, I see this.
`.field public static final screen_scan:I = 0x7f090185`

This error occurs with all @BindView annotations.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a compatibility problem with JDK 17.

You could try this workaround: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1686#issuecomment-1514927085

Bear in mind that Butterknife has been deprecated for a long time. If you can, you should migrate to view binding!

Comment: The workaround did the trick, thanks!

I noticed that Gradle 8 is now by default using non-final resource ID's.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/54fe2d86%5E%21/

Comment: what changes did you do? can you please explain.   @A.Silva